# HLOOKUP in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my excel file:

[image]

I need a formula that would starts in cell J2 in this excel spreadsheet that does the following: It would look for the letter C (column) in the filled matrix, and then gives me the value. For example the first value in J2 would be 43,24 and then I would drag the formula till the end (14th row, with the filled matrix FIXED  $$).

The Final output should be like this:

[image]

My problem is that I cant fix the filled matrix ($$) in my HLOOKUP/VLOOKUP.

Any help guys?

Thanks

Comment: You need one INDEX with a MATCH for the row and MATCH for the column.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for your time. I imagine this. My HLOOKUP didnt went well. How can I do this. I have no Experience in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one INDEX with a MATCH for the row and a MATCH for the column (if you're looking to change up the `C` and `F`), something like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$14,MATCH($I2,$A$2:$A$14,0),MATCH(J$1,$B$1:$G$1,0))
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If you don't need to do a match on the date, then simply remove that part of the formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$14,,MATCH(J$1,$B$1:$G$1,0))
```

Or if you want to use HLOOKUP, then like this:

```
=HLOOKUP(J$1,$B$1:$G$14,ROW(),TRUE)
```

[image]